# How to deploy a generated apk to a Wear OS device without Play Store

Tags: android, deployment, apk, wear-os

For development and testing purposes I would like to install a (signed) apk on some different Wear OS-devices.

With android studio and ADB this is possible for devices in my local (wifi) network area.

As the app is not in a publishable state yet (it is still under development) I do not want to upload it to Google Play Store - I want some friends only to download and install it on their own wearables.

On phone or tablet devices this can be easily achieved by hosting the apk-file on a web server. By downloading it on the mobile device from there it can be installead just by accepting a security exception.

On a Wear OS wearable, however, I do not find any possibilities to download and install apk's directly. So I wonder how I can distribute a Wear OS-apk to some restricted users groups without Play Store? Anybody's any idea?

Thanx,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advice you to use one of the [internal test tracks](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/test-tracks) that the Google Play Store provides.

1. It's already there and you're most likely familiar with the upload process
2. It's super easy to grant access to specific individuals or a group of
   people
3. It can easily be promoted into alpha/beta/production when
   you have a stable version